# Dynamic pages / menu in php

Tags: php, dynamic-pages

Hi I am working on some sort of a CMS page and I want to show on the `/index.php` page a list of all articles availble like `/index.php?p=Art1`.

And I have no clue on how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my `index.php` code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login-layout.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="dialog-box">
            <h2 style="font-size: 200%;margin-bottom: 0;">Pagini Noi</h2>
            <h3 style="text-align: right; font-size:100%;margin-top: 0;"><a href="login.php">Logheazate</a> pentru a edita paginile</h3>
            <div class="pages">
                <!-- Pagini \/ -->
                <?php
                    include('config.php');

                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Config.php` contains the connection to the database `$db` is the variable name that i use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /index.php?p=Art1 method is actually a $_GET that you need to fetch. In your current example you would do:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
```

Which if you would later echo:

```
echo $p;
```

you would get

```
Art1
```

but even before that, you should provide us with some database query example that you wish to do so we could show you how variable $p is passed on to a query that then selects the wanted rows from the table in your database. For simple mysql query you can check here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

WARNING: be sure to use mysqli_real_escape_string($p) in order to get a minimum protection from SQL injections.